# load fragment from Activity layouts overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to load fragment layout button click on activity. When I do this it successfully redirects to the fragment but the thing is the fragment layout overlapped with the activity layout. Please help me.

This is my Activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This my fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Add"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

The ThreeFragment extends Fragment and in Activity inside button click this is is how I load the fragement. No errors occur, the only thing is the views are overlapping.

```
  AddPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = new FourFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

    });
```

Comment: set background to the layouts it will do the trick for you

Comment: I have tried but not what i want I want to totally replace the activity layout from fragment

Comment: @SiluniUpeksha Then use replace instead of add while fragment transaction.

Comment: I have tried the layouts still overlapping

Comment: @SiluniUpeksha Try moving you `frameContainer` inside `Linear Layout` itself and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put background on your fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="three"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Add"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

or clear other fragment before adding new:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Comment: It work but I want to set background in white if i put dark color it works

Comment: @SiluniUpeksha can you add some screenshot so i can see what overlaps. or try fragmentManager.popBackStack();

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
 android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout6">

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />
   </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no its not working I want to display whole fragment layout py replacing it with activity layout

Comment: I have tried but not what i want I want to totally replace the activity layout from fragment the fragment layout show below activity layout thats not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new FourFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: What is the difference it contains then OP ?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment

Comment: still same views are over lapping

Comment: add or replace not working still views are over lappng

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fragment completely hiding activity layout, consider using [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Also check out the excellent [cliff notes](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment) to know how to make the dialog full screen.

It basically involved these steps:

1. Derive your fragment class from DialogFragment.
2. Show fragment as dialog from your activity.
3. Ensure the dialog fragment is styled to be full screen.